# Rails how to get leaf nodes of model linked list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to create a linked list of models, sort of this structure

```
A <- B <- C // (C is the leaf)
D <- E <- F // (F is the leaf)
G <- H // (H is the leaf)
I // (I has no children, I itself is the leaf)
```

I have done it in a ruby model like this

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child, class_name: "Node", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Node"
end
```

I want to get a list of leaf nodes only i.e. `C`, `F`, `H` and `I`, I know how I'll do this in SQL, how do I do it in rails? I am on rails 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pure ruby solution and not so performant:

Node.all.select{|n| n.child.blank?}

Basically writing a SQL solution in rails:

```
Node.joins("LEFT JOIN nodes AS children ON nodes.id = children.parent_id").where("children.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: thanks, I decided to change the direction of the links i.e. instead of child storing `parent_id`, now parent stores `child_id` and it works for me since the relationship is one to one. then I am getting leaf nodes using `Node.where('child_id IS NULL')`